# Python: Regex for German mobile numbers

Tags: python, regex, mobile

I am trying to find a Python regex which catches simple German mobile phone numbers.

They typically look like this:

- +4915368831169
- +491771399487

Please see my [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NE2YP5/7) on regex101.

EDIT: I have added more examples to the demo!

Comment: Why is `+49177178796` not allowed?

Comment: According to my knowledge it is missing one digit (it's too short). You have other informations? I might be wrong. Numbers that I could find were all like the ones listed in my demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve it: `\+491\d{9,10}$`

See: https://regex101.com/r/NE2YP5/6

Explanation of what I did/ change:

- You need to escape the `+`: `\+`
- Every german mobile number starts with a `1`
- Instead of `[0-9]` you can say `\d`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will mark it as my personal solution once the time is up

Comment: One last question: Since these numbers are in the middle of a long text, there might be a white space behind it. Therefore I have slightly changed my demo. Please have a look.

Comment: Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/XHVndZ/1